# SAS Merge conversion in SQL with condition

Tags: sql-server, sas

I am trying to convert the below SAS Merge code to SQL and for me it’s the first time to convert the SAS script to SQL.

```
merge tb208;
 proc sort data=tb208;
 by rsn_cde;
 run;
 proc sort data=dclhcl;
 by rsn_cde;
 run;
 data dclhcl;
 merge tb208 (in=t) dclhcl (in=d);
 by rsn_cde;
 if d;
 run;
```

My conversion for the above merge in SQL

```
SELECT t.*
            ,d.*
FROM tb208 t 
JOIN dclhcl d ON t.rsn_cde = d.rsn_cde
```

Post JOIN condition I am unable to convert the If Condition in SAS to SQL. Can anyone help me with an solution for the above SAS Merge conversion.

Comment: Just saying, but this is the *3rd* (undeleted) question you've asked in as many days for converting SAS to T-SQL; perhaps you should really be taking the time to learn the respective dialects. After all, it's *you* who will need to be able to support the code. "Translate this code block" questions tend to not be useful to future readers either and can attract downvotes. If there's a specific tool you aren't sure how to use in one language, asking about that is fine, but a search may well give you a wealth of existing questions on how to achieve that too.

Answer (score 0):

The MERGE statement here is mapped to SQL right outer join.

```
SELECT t.*
        ,d.*
FROM tb208 t 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN dclhcl d ON t.rsn_cde = d.rsn_cde
```

Pay attention to the following differences between SAS and RDBMS:

1. Missing values (aka NULL in SQL). In SAS it is just a unique value that would go to the beginning of the merged data set. In the databases, your mileage may vary.
2. If you have multiple records with the same rsn_code in both left and right tables (many-to-many merge), you CAN NOT reproduce SAS semantics using SQL.